# Panel with JScrollPane - Maintain preferred height for components

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, vertical-scrolling

I have a mainPanel with JScrollPane.
This initially has a single button inside with a fixed height.

The height of mainPanel should be fixed at 3 times the height of the button.

So, initially the mainPanel should the button and some amount of free space below the button.

Now, I dynamically add buttons to mainPanel which have to get added vertically and after three buttons the Scrollbars have to kick in.

Which Layout Manager should I use for mainPanel to achieve this effect?

Comment: the panel you need to worry about is inside the scrollpane.  For stacking - try BoxLayout

Comment: Implement the [`Scrollable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollable) interface.

Comment: So you want some auto scroll stuff?

Comment: I want scroll but initially when the panel contains only one button, the button should not fill up the entire space, but rather have it's preferred size and leave the remaining space empty. I have implemented the Scrollbar and everything, but I am not able to manage to allow the buttons retain their preffered height